# Configure TeamCity built-in authentication password complexity requirements

Tags: passwords, teamcity, built-in

We are currently using built-in authentication for our TC server which means it is all managed by the TC server. It appears out of the box there is no password complexity, min length etc. required and I would like to increase this to at least a min # of characters.
I have searched high and low in TC admin to try and find any settings that will help me do this but to no avail. Additionally, I have searched all the conf files on our TC server and their online doco, googled it etc. etc. but nothing on how to achieve this.

Does anyone know whether it is even possible, and if so, how to do it? If not, I guess I will have to look at another authentication provider but was hoping not to have to do that.

Note: We are using the latest version of TC Server installed on a Windows Server (TeamCity Professional 2022.10.3 (build 117072)).

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research, it seems you cannot increase the password complexity/requirements for the Built-in authentication module in TeamCity On-Premises.

The solution I have chosen was to swap over to using one of the supported third party [HTTP/SSO authentication modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2022.10/configuring-authentication-settings.html#HTTP+%2F+SSO+Authentication+Modules).